# Adding new record to "buffered store" in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, buffered

In my application I've a grid with buffered store.
On click of row of grid, alert will be shown.
I want to add a new row to grid i.e., add a new record to store (should not be saved in back-end until user peforms some save action). The same added record can also be deleted if user chooses to do so.

Currently tried the below approach..

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[0],
gridStore= grid.getStore();
var bufferedStoreMap = gridStore.getData().map[currentPage]; //currentPage = 1
var mapVal = bufferedStoreMap.value;

gridStore.totalCount++;
mapVal.unshift(Ext.create('Ext.data.Model',{name:'test'}));
grid.getView().refresh();
```

With the above code new record is added to store, but grid events like click are not working.
Getting the below error.
[image]

Any idea on achieving this??
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The buffered store doesn't support local modifications, it's essentially a read only data source once the data is loaded via the server.

Comment: Do you suggest any other way to achieve my requirement??

Comment: Not without a large amount of work. How many records are you expecting to load?

Comment: so create a model to store data, then throw it at the server, then reload buffered store?

Comment: @Dawesi I cannot throw it at server until user decides to save it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli 
Not without a large amount of work. How many records are you expecting to load?
Im not clear with your question?? Is your intention to know total no.of records available or no.of records that I'm adding??

If it's about intial load.. it's a very large dataset where we have more than 1000 records.
If it's about newly created records.. then it would be 3 to 4 at a time

Comment: 1000 records isn't much, why not just load the entire store?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli It's more than 1000. You can assume it would be in lakhs.

Comment: any inputs on achieving this??